# How to change the complete wordpress structure to show most recent posts according to last modified

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In wordpress blog, posts appears according to most recent (new). Here i want to change it to show all recent posts according to last modified. Does it possible?

I don't know where the code is, checked theme functions but not found anything.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is your theme name?

Comment: @ShitalMarakana frontier theme

Comment: ok. please share blog page website url.

Comment: sorry it is in localhost. Just using for testing purpose, with close ports. I am not familiar with wordpress, so i thought somebody could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this hook to get the post order by last modified.

```
function custom_loop( $query ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_loop' );
```

Use this in functions.php

Comment: Thanks brother. Solved